# How can I pipe bash output to a file and to the terminal at the same time?

Tags: linux, bash, stderr, piping

This is a really basic question, but I couldn't find it asked this basically in an existing question, so please flag this if it's been answered before.

I want to pipe stderr from a bash command to a file, but not prevent it from being displayed on the terminal during execution.

More specifically, I have this .sh file:

```
nslookup MadeUpName
nslookup MadeUpName2
nslookup MadeUpName3
```

and I'm doing this:

```
. ./myScript.sh 2>errors.txt
```

This works to pipe error messages to *errors.txt*, but now I can't see the errors in the terminal as they happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tee` for displaying error and writing to an error file:

```
myScript.sh 2> >(tee error.log; exit)
```

If you want further information about this technique, see [this page](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).